# Tomcat7: Asynchronous Servlet not working

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

I've configured Tomcat7 to have a single connector thread that posts jobs to a pool of background threads, which complete requests asynchronously. Each request has a delay of 1 second. My test (JMeter) spins up 5 threads and makes 5 simultaneous requests. I'm expecting the single connector thread to process each of the 5 requests immediately. Instead, it's waiting for the previous task  (running on a bg thread) to finish before servicing the next one.

To clarify, my configuration tries to imitate the thread architecture of "single-threaded" asynchronous servers like Node.js and Tornado.

**Connector:**

> ```
> <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>            connectionTimeout="20000"
>            maxThreads="1"
>            URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
> ```

**Servlet:**

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, value = "/testasync", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class TestAsync extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestAsync.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int NUM_WORKER_THREADS = 100;

private ExecutorService executor = null;

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_WORKER_THREADS);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync(); // obtain async context
    ac.setTimeout(0); // test only, no timeout

    LOG.info("received request on: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    this.executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                LOG.info("processing request: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                LOG.info("processed request:"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
                ac.getResponse().getWriter().write("<h1>Request Processed</h1>");
                ac.complete();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info("failed:" + e);
            }
        }
    });
    LOG.info("posted request on: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

}

**Logs:**

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:00 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: received request on: 16

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:00 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: posted request on: 16

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:00 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processing request: 26

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:05 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processed request:26

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:05 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: received request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:05 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: posted request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:05 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processing request: 28

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:10 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processed request:28

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:10 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: received request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:10 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: posted request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:10 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processing request: 29

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:15 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processed request:29

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:15 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: received request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:15 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: posted request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:15 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processing request: 30

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:20 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processed request:30

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:20 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: received request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:20 PM TestAsync doGet INFO: posted request on: 27

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:20 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processing request: 31

Sep 17, 2013 12:26:25 PM TestAsync$1 run INFO: processed request:31

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is down to the use of the BIO connector in Tomcat. This is the default connector in a Tomcat installation. The [BIO connector blocks to read every request until the response is written](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Connector_Comparison), and with a single thread in the pool, you get to see the behavior you described.

If you increase the `maxThreads` to more than 1, you'll see that other threads pick up the incoming requests, but the connector would still block new connections until the existing threads are free. To move to the model you desire (a single request thread that is freed up the moment you want to delegate processing to another), you need switch to a connector that doesn't block (NIO or APR/Native). You'll also possibly need to increase the size of the thread pool (this really depends on whether the request processing thread does only one job or not and whether it is overloaded).

Comment: I thought the purpose of Asynchronous Servlet was to decouple the connector thread pool from the processing thread pool, such that a connector thread is not wasted (can be returned) if the request has a long delay. What then is the benefit of Asynchronous Servlets? My configuration was meant to imitate the thread architecture of asynchronous servers like Node.js or Tornado.

Comment: @lairtech Also note that the Tomcat NIO connector does simulated blocking, so it may not be as performant as you expect. The APR/Native connector might turn out to be better.

Comment: I removed the dependency on JAX-RS to isolate the issue. Using Http11NioProtocol did not work. This was my config: <Connector maxThreads="1" URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8002" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: That is odd. Request processing is certainly detached from the original thread going by the thread Ids. But going by the 5 second delay between each request being processed, it looks like (1) the original thread is not returned to the pool immediately or (2) is prevented from processing a new request (by design). (1) would be a bug in Tomcat which is unlikely. Persistent connections might contribute to (2) so you might want to see if closing the response or not using keep-alive helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a NIO connector and a executor pool as described [here](http://blog.yamanyar.com/2013/09/dont-forget-to-use-nio-if-you-are-doing.html).

If you do not have really good reasons; there is no reason to limit your self with one thread at front. Please see the url I provided.